# Can I have a List view and images icon with textview on the Android

Tags: android, image, listview, layout

I need to have a listview like it is having for the following android application

Since I cannot post the image this is how it should be

---

INAGE Over here | Some Free text
                | User name etc

---

Here is your task

---

### Task 1                     >

### Task 2                     >

---

Task 1 & Task 2 are the list which would be dynamically picked up from the DB

I am trying to have a list with a textview the problem is that I can only get the List or the text view not both any point of time I have even tried relative layout in that case i see the text overlapping

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:id="@+id/g_tracker_layout" 
     android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">  

    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                        android:id="@+id/question1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:autoLink="all"
                        android:text="@string/question1"
                        /> 
   <ListView android:id="@+id/ListView01"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Any help guidance would be really helpful in achiving the layout similar to this

Following is the snippet in the onCreateMethod()

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.g_tracker_home); 
        this.dh = new TrackerDAO(this); 
        lv1=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListView01); 
        trackerObj = dh.selectAll();
        if(trackerObj!=null) {
        List<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(Tracker obj : trackerObj ){
          al.add(obj.getTrackerName());
        }
           lv1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 , al));
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

[Here is an excerpt](http://commonsware.com/Android/excerpt.pdf) from one of my books showing how to take control over the creation of list rows, so you can mix text and images. The sample projects described in that excerpt can be found [in this directory](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/FancyLists/) of the book's GitHub repository.

In a nutshell, for an `ArrayAdapter`, you will need to subclass it and override `getView()` to update both the text and the image.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response I did went through the expert of your book for creating a list from an Array and it was quiet helpful 
Problem is on the screen I want to have a have a LIST displayed along with other components and I am extending the Activity class instead of extending ListActivity

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/g_tracker_layout" 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">  
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/question1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:autoLink="all"
        android:text="@string/question1"/>
    <ListView android:id="@+id/ListView01"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/question1"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

> > I have even tried relative layout in that case i see the text overlapping

That's really nice. After you get some expertise, you will see that `RelativeLayout` is one of the best layout schemes. In this simple case you could use `LinearLayout` too, but when things start getting complex, it's better to use `RelativeLayout` which is really flexible and will allow you to reduce the need of nest elements.

Comment: I am having the same problem as the text is overlaying with the list and somehow cannot figure it out