# How to make a android ListView with a ImageView and TextView in Each Line?

Tags: android, listview, textview, imageview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I have a List view and images icon with textview on the Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3638322/can-i-have-a-list-view-and-images-icon-with-textview-on-the-android)

How to make a android ListView with a ImageView and TextView in Each Line?

I am working on a Android app that is going to have a screen with a ListView on it and its going to need a ImageView and a TextView on each line... can someone please help me out with some clues and samples

Comment: [Android Developer Resources](http://developer.android.com/resources/index.html)

Answer (score 4):

You will need to teach your `ListAdapter` how to do that. This may be by subclassing it and overriding `getView()`, if this is an `ArrayAdapter`. You can design your own custom rows and use those, pouring in the data for the `ImageView` and `TextView` as the rows get loaded.

[Here is a free excerpt](http://commonsware.com/Android/excerpt.pdf) from [one of my books](http://commonsware.com/Android) that goes through the process. [Here is the source code](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/FancyLists) to the sample projects profiled in that chapter.

Answer (score 0):

In short, you should use a ListActivity. You'll be able to set the layout xml for each row.

Take a look at this 
[tutorial:](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-listview/)

What you need to do is the same, but adapt it to have an ImageView in addition to a textview.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, you will need to extend an adapter and use it in your ListActivity. Make an XML file with a TextView and an ImageView (using LinearLayout or any other layout). You can add IDs to TextView and ImageView so you can change them according to the position in the list.

Here is a code example that creates three rows and sets the text in them to a, b, c.

```
public class MyActivity extends ListActivity {

    private String[] data = {"a","b","c"};

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setListAdapter(new MyAdapter(this, R.layout.rowxml, data));
    }

    private class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

        public MyAdapter(Context c, int i, String[] s) {
            super(c, i, s);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View v, ViewGroup parent) {
            if (v == null) {
                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(
                    Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v = vi.inflate(R.layout.rowxml, null);
            }

            TextView tw = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text);
            if (tw != null) tw.setText(data[position]);

            // You can do something similar with the ImageView  

            return v;
        }
    }
}
```